# Can I create a calculated field like % of total?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I know I can create the % of Total by selecting the option from the Value Field Settings > Show Values As section, but I'd really like to show my percentage as an index (% of col total * 100)

Can I get formula with the calculated fields?  I can't seem to get any kinds of sum() or total() to work in the create calculated field pane

EDIT: ADDED IMAGE FOR CONTEXT
[image]

I created an example of what I'm trying to achieve: I just want to display the %of Col Total, but as a whole number; it's a straightforward calculation, but I can't seem to recreate it as a pivot calc.  I'm also open to reformatting that output, but I haven't been successful doing that either

Comment: Can you post a data example of the input and expected output? But at first sight, it looks kind of difficult, because calculated fields in Pivot Tables don't allow any kind of functions, just basic mathematical operations

Comment: Good idea: I added a brief example/image to the original post